# How to render view to an element in the default layout from the controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an element in my default layout which I would like to see on all the pages in my website.This element has a a form with a submit button and goes to Quotes controller index action.On clicking the submit button,I want to  render to the particular element from the controller but I am getting error that a view does not exist for the particular controller.How to render to an element in the default layout from a controller?Can somebody please give me ideas...

Comment: We can help you a lot easier if you post some code. Your controller action and maybe the element code would be useful. And please clarify something: want do you want to render to the element? The whole html? Some variables?

Comment: It sounds like you have a quotation form element on all pages and once submitted you want to use the element as the view file for the form validation/etc. - If this is the case, it's bad practice. You would be better to create a view which either shows the form with validation errors or the success state (be that a message or not), then make sure to disable the element on this page only as you don't want the form to appear twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the book:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render